# using enum with pattern builder in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

im trying to learn how to use pattern builder. i could get it to work until i tried to use enum.

I tried to change the code couple of times and each time had different error. right now the error is Incompatible types.

Please can you help bringing this code to working state and if you have suggestions to improve the code it would be great.

thanks.

EDIT:
now it seems to be okay, but how do i use it with the builder inside the main?
this was the code i used

main:

```
Person person3 = new Person.PersonBuilder("Julliete", "Kaplan" )
            .status(); // what should i write here to set the status?
```

person class

```
public class Person
{
private final String name;
private final String lastname;
private final int age;

//My enum im trying to use
private Status status;
public enum Status
{
    SINGLE ("Single"), MARRIED ("Married"), WIDOWER ("Widower");

    private String status;

    private Status(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus()
    {
        return this.status;
    }
}

//builder
private Person(PersonBuilder builder) {
    this.name = builder.name;
    this.lastname = builder.lastname;
    this.age = builder.age;
    this.status = builder.status;
}

//GETTERS
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person : "+this.name+", "+this.lastname+", "+this.age;
}

//PersonBuilder
public static class PersonBuilder
{
    private final String name;
    private final String lastname;
    private int age;
    private Status status;

    public PersonBuilder(String name, String lastname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public PersonBuilder age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public PersonBuilder status(Status status)
    {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }

    public Person build() {
        Person person =  new Person(this);
        return person;
    }

}
```

Comment: is it any reason why your enum is private? if you keep it as public, Person and PersonBuilder can share it

Comment: The enum `Status` in `Person` is a **different** enum than the one in `PersonBuilder`, even though they have the same name and content.

Comment: On a point of style, I would call the `PersonBuilder` class simply `Builder`: you probably know that it builds a `Person`, it's inside that class.

Comment: Thanks, can you recheck my code? i will update it.

Comment: currentlyu your enum is define as inner class of `Person`, to make it work, you need to make it static or define it in different file as normal class

Answer (score 0):

Don't define another `Status` enum inside the builder: reuse the one defined in the `Person` class.

Otherwise, you've got to map from instances of `PersonBuilder.Status` to instances of `Person.Status`: they are entirely separate types.

Currently this mapping is trivial: you can use `Person.Status.valueOf(personBuilderStatus.name())` - but you have to ensure that you update both at the same time to have identical values (or at least that `PersonBuilder.Status` maps to a subset of `Person.Status`), which is an unnecessary maintenance burden going forwards.